# Calling Java code from MATLAB, synchronizing

Tags: java, matlab

If I call some java function from MATLAB, can I expect, that the following MATLAB code will wait the return from java function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will wait for the main thread. But not for others.

Under some cases you can abuse the [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) command to finish the other threads.

Comment: Does it mean that if i call java function and this function wait for answer from user, MATLAB will wait also? Which thread is java function? Do you know where I can read about it?

Comment: I suppose if it is programmed this way it will wait. At http://http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ a lot of Matlab-Java is discussed in detail. There's even a big book - though I couldn't read it so far.